# Dump PRAGMAs from sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, export, dump

I am dumping an `sqlite` database using the `.dump` command, but noticed it doesn't dump the `PRAGMA`s. For example, the [`user_version`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version) PRAGMA is not exported.

Is there a way to include the set `PRAGMA`s in the dump?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @CL., Sorry, forgot about it :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You'd have to execute the `PRAGMA user_version` separately, or change the source code of the shell.